# My Pager function is resetting all my checkboxes in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

In a partial view I have a AjaxPager function

Items Partial view

```
@foreach (Items item in Model)
{
    <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="clink" 
         value="@(item.Name)"/>@item.Name</label></li>
}
```

The above works fine however the problem is: Lets say the user has selected 2 checkboxes which are checked now. But when the user clicks the Pager items the list of items is updated but this also causes all checkboxs to become unchecked. How can i sort this ???

Comment: You must store the state of each checkbox. You could store this in some hidden field in the page (outside the partial view area) and then restore the state after the partial ajax reaload, or even send the state to the server and then mark each checkbox when you call the MVC Controller.

Answer (score 0):

actually partial view call updates the exited view from the latest response come from server , that means the current state of anything inside your partial view will be lost , in this scenario you cold :

1. Save check box's references to a other variable outside of the partial view.
2. Return partial view with checkboxes selected which currently have check=true status

Thanks